# Python typehint a Union return type from a tuple of types as argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I am writing a method that takes a tuple of types and returns an object that is an instance of one of those types or `None`. I would like to type hint the function to show that it returns an instance of one the types passed or `None` as a Union. However, the typehint I have instead hints the return type as being a Union of the lowest common base class of the elements in the tuple or `None`. How can I fix this?

In my case the types happen to have a shared base class, but ideally I would like a solution that works with any tuple of types.

```py
from typing import Union, Optional, TypeVar

class Base: ...
class A(Base): ...
class B(Base): ...
class C(Base): ...

def get_data() -> tuple[Base, ...]:
    return (A(), C())

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Base)

# I have also tried typehinting the return value as Optional[Union[T]] but
# that didn't change anything.
def find_instance(types: tuple[type[T], ...]) -> Optional[T]:
    for element in get_data():
        if isinstance(element, types):
            return element
    return None

def find_instance2(types: tuple[T, ...]) -> Optional[T]:
    for element in get_data():
        if isinstance(element, types):
            return element
    return None

# The final typehints I'm looking for
a: Optional[Base] = find_instance((Base,))  # Inferred as Optional[Base]
b: Optional[Union[B, C]] = find_instance((B, C))  # Also inferred as Optional[Base]

# Both c and d are inferred as Optional[Type[Base]]
c: Optional[Base] = find_instance2((Base,))
d: Optional[Union[B, C]] = find_instance2((B, C))
```

Checking the above code using mypy gives the following errors:

```
test.py:18: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Base", expected "Optional[T]")
test.py:23: error: Argument 2 to "isinstance" has incompatible type "Tuple[T, ...]"; expected "Union[type, Tuple[Union[type, Tuple[Any, ...]], ...]]"
test.py:24: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Base", expected "Optional[T]")
test.py:29: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[Base]", variable has type "Union[B, C, None]")
test.py:32: error: Value of type variable "T" of "find_instance2" cannot be "Type[Base]"
test.py:32: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[Type[Base]]", variable has type "Optional[Base]")
test.py:33: error: Value of type variable "T" of "find_instance2" cannot be "Type[Base]"
test.py:33: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[Type[Base]]", variable has type "Union[B, C, None]")
Found 8 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: This is because of this open bug: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4625#issuecomment-368061998. Because your declaration has `tuple[type[T], ...]`, a `Union` ends up getting used within a `type`. But the linked issue shows how it gets collapsed to the base class, `object` in their case and `Base` in your case.